# Maximum request length exceeded iis 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, web-config

I appreciate this has been asked numerous times before, but i cannot seem to get this working.

I have the following values in my config file:

```
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="16384" executionTimeout="7200" />
```

and

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
     <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="16777216" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
```

I am however getting a maximum request length exception thrown.

The content length of my message is :Content-Length: 7785556

Can anyone suggest a setting i may have overlooked?

Comment: Might be wrong, but isn't 7785556 greater than 16384?

Comment: 7785556 is in bytes, 16384 is in KB

Comment: Have you tried just setting it to a massive value as a test?

Comment: I set them both the max allowed (Int.Max)

Comment: Int.Max isn't a valid value.  The upper limit depends on the version of IIS you are running and the framework, but it's usually 1GB (or more depending).

Answer (score 1):

I had to add:

```
 <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="16384" executionTimeout="7200" />
```

To my machine.config.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on Framework version, under 2.0 **httpRuntime** works. On other Framework versions you should be using **requestFiltering** section to define this limit.

Answer (score 0):

Check this microsoft support link
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;295626

Comment: I  am not using the HtmlInputFile control